# DNS lookup aliasing of hostnames (not IP aliases), probably via dnsmasq

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, alias, dnsmasq

I'd like to be able to set up a host, say "`eg`", to be an alias to some server on the internet, say "`example.example.com`".

I just need this functionality to be available from my local machine.  I'm running dnsmasq on that machine, which is running ubuntu 9.10.

Is there a way to configure dnsmasq or the resolver subsystem (including avahi) to resolve that alias hostname via the actual hostname, so that `eg` will resolve to the ip address of `example.example.com`?

Answer (score 6):

The dnsmasq manpage says:

> `--cname=<cname>,<target>`
>
> Return a CNAME record which indicates that `<cname>` is really
>   `<target>`. There are significant
>   limitations on the target; it must be
>   a DNS name which is known to dnsmasq
>   from /etc/hosts (or additional hosts
>   files) or from DHCP. If the target
>   does not satisfy this criteria, the
>   whole cname is ignored. The cname must
>   be unique, but it is permissable to
>   have more than one cname pointing to
>   the same target.

I think the "known target" criteria will make it unsuitable for your requirements.

I do know that [Unbound](http://www.unbound.net/) does support this feature, though.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work because the host that I want the alias to target isn't local.  Thanks for the tip on Unbound, I'll check that out.  Though I'd rather  not have to learn a whole other way of doing what dnsmasq already does.. :(

Comment: +1 for unbound... and the pun on bind :)

Answer (score 2):

In your dnsmasq.conf add this line

expand-hosts

This will allow you to create a name that can be used.

This was not asked but if you want to all devices to use it set up the dhcp options. Just for a guide here is my config.

```
expand-hosts # allows /etc/hosts to be used
dhcp-range=192.168.2.2,192.168.2.50,255.255.255.0,24h #Range and lease time
dhcp-option=3,192.168.2.1 #gateway
dhcp-option=6,192.168.2.51 #dns server
dhcp-option=28,192.168.0.255
```

I am runing this on a Raspberry pi  that is also acting as a pi-hole and webserver.

Comment: how does that solve the OP's problem?

Answer (score -3):

Try this in your /etc/hosts:

```
example.example.com         eg
```

Although most entries are in the form

```
1.2.3.4                     hostname.alias.example.com
```

a host-to-host alias should work too.

Comment: Does that work?  If so it's not documented as such in `man hosts` under ubuntu.  It mentions that I can give an alias *in addition to* an IP address and canonical hostname, but in this case that won't work because the IP address for that host is dynamic.

Comment: Confirmed that this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't - I thought I'd seen a colleague using it but they couldn't get it to work either.