# Resolve a domain name to CNAME alias locally using dnsmasq

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, dnsmasq

I'd like to resolve a domain name `somedomain.com` to a CNAME (AWS load balancer, e.g. `some-balancer-1213231237.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com`), but **only locally**.

What I mean to achieve is that whenever I try to visit `somedomain.com`, I want to be served by the above mentioned load-balancer - this should only be limited to my own computer.

It's not possible to achieve this by editing `/etc/hosts` as in there only A records (IP addresses) can be mapped. I read somewhere that `dnsmasq` would be the most robust solution to achieve this. However, the documentation is very unclear about how this can be achieve. I'd appreciate your advice and perhaps a piece of config with an example. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know if it's possible with dnsmasq (I think it probably isn't). But if you're willing to use Bind, it'd be quite easy.

Comment: I found an alternative with Unbound. https://serverfault.com/a/137984/368240

Answer (score 14):

You can add the following to your configuration file in `dnsmasq`:

```
cname=somedomain.com,some-balancer-1213231237.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

as specified in the [man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html):

```
--cname=<cname>,[<cname>,]<target>[,<TTL>]
```

> Return a CNAME record which indicates that `<cname>` is really `<target>`. There are significant limitations on the target; it must be a DNS name which is known to dnsmasq from /etc/hosts (or additional hosts files), from DHCP, from `--interface-name` or from another `--cname`. If the target does not satisfy this criteria, the whole cname is ignored. The cname must be unique, but it is permissible to have more than one cname pointing to the same target. Indeed it's possible to declare multiple cnames to a target in a single line, like so: `--cname=cname1,cname2,target`
>
> If the time-to-live is given, it overrides the default, which is zero or the value of `--local-ttl`. The value is a positive integer and gives the time-to-live in seconds.

As the man page specifies, you will have to define the target in your */etc/hosts* file though:

```
203.0.113.80   some-balancer-1213231237.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

So I'm not sure this would be very useful to you.

Comment: I get that this is how the dnsmasq manual is written, but them referring to the owner name as `cname` when it's clearly the record data that is the cname (what they call `target`) just makes for very confusing reading (particularly as they keep referring to `cname` in the text, with the opposite meaning of what one would expect). I don't know if there's any way to fix that without just giving up on quoting the manual, though.

Comment: A CNAME record in dnsmasq won't work for this use case. As written in the dnsmaq manual that you quoted: "there are significant limitations on the target". An external target like what @luqo33 mentioned (e.g. `some-balancer-1213231237.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com`) won't be accepted by dnsmasq.

Comment: Note that at least in version 2.82 this behavior seems to have changed and external targets work as expected.

Comment: I can confirm that it works for external targets in 2.81. Using `nslookup`, I can see the canonical name.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work for version 2.76-16.  "dig" reports the cname record correctly, and I can resolve the target, but dnsmasq doesn't deliver the target's IP directly from the cname.  The whole point is that the target is a dynamic address, so it must be provided by an upstream server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind, that **the to be resolved** hostname has to be added **to the /etc/hosts** file too !
E.g.: the right part in the hosts file:

```
10.1.1.1 ip1.example.com
```

dnsmasq.conf entry:
cname=cname.example.com,ip1.example.com

Test:

```
ping  cname.example.com
PING ip1.example.com (10.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ip1.example.com (10.1.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
```

That's all it takes ;-)